# How to Show Author in Custom Post Type Author in All (For Eg: Agent (is Custome Post Type))

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

My Custom Post type is Agent and i want to show Author List In All Agent page Quick Edit Option Like Default Post And page Shows and All users even he/she is subscriber our Custom User Type
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9jiY.png)

Answer (score 3):

One of the many args you can pass to `register_post_type()` is `supports` which is an alias for calling `add_post_type_support()` directly.

`register_post_type([
    'supports' => ['author']
])`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_cpt_support_author() {
    add_post_type_support( 'my_cpt', 'author' );
}
add_action('init', 'my_cpt_support_author');
```

add this code in you function.php